# Fill html form input fields with MySQL data onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've got a MySQL database and a few php/html forms that work fine. What I want to do, but haven't been able to figure out, is to display a form that can be filled when I enter a key value to retrieve a record from the database and fill that data in the input fields of the form like Name, Address etc..

Like: Enter Customer ID to fill in all Customer Details in the form automatically.

Anyone have any examples of how to do this? I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking ... see [ask]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: This was my first Question Sorry I was not able to ask it correctly..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8pk0bgfz/7/ - It has my form for understanding

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP, make an SQL query that selects all the data you need. Then use `print` or `echo` to replace the value of an input field inside a script tag.

For example:

```
<?php
  echo "<script>Elem.value='".$var."';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/8pk0bgfz/7 - It has my form for understanding